# Неправильное увеличение массива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, объекты, динамические-массивы

Есть код, записывающий данные из базы данных (переменная `data.output[i]` берется из базы данных)  в массив `productcarditems`

```js
let productcarditems = [];
let productcardobject = {};
let checkMemory;

for (let i = 0; i < data.result.countrecords; i++) {
  productcardobject["imagepath"] = data.output[i]['imagepath'];
  console.log('Путь к рисунку ' + productcardobject["imagepath"]);
  productcardobject["monoblockname"] = data.output[i]['monoblockname'];
  productcardobject["color"] = data.output[i]['color'];
  productcardobject["Диагональ"] = data.output[i]['screendiagonal'];
  productcardobject["разрешение"] = data.output[i]['resolution'];
  productcardobject["Тип процессора"] = data.output[i]['cputype'];
  productcardobject["Частота процессора"] = data.output[i]['frequency'];
  productcardobject["Оперативная память (RAM)"] = data.output[i]['ramsize'];
  productcardobject["Графический контроллер"] = data.output[i]['videocard'];
  if (data.output[i]['memorytype'] == 'SSD') {
    productcardobject["Объем SSD"] = data.output[i]['sizememorydata'];
    checkMemory = 'SSD';
  } else if (data.output[i]['memorytype'] == 'HDD') {
    productcardobject["Объем HDD"] = data.output[i]['sizememorydata'];
    checkMemory = 'HDD';
  };
  productcardobject["GoodsPrice"] = data.output[i]['price'];
  productcarditems.splice(i, 0, productcardobject);
  console.log('productcarditems[i]');
  console.log(productcarditems[i]);
  /*
  console.log('After productcarditems[i]');
  console.log(productcardobject);
  */
}
console.log('productcarditems output');
console.log(productcarditems);
```

В результате массив `productcarditems` записывается 17 раз последний элемент массива, а должно быть 17 различных объектов `productcardobject` из базы данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// let productcardobject = {};
...
for (let i = 0; i < data.result.countrecords; i++) {
  let productcardobject = {};
  ...
```

Comment: @krasnodarprogrammer Я прекрасно понял, что Вам нужно, и прекрасно ответил, что для этого надо сделать.